# The Ramda.JS tag is missing from the top users's Developer Story

Tags: discussion, bug, developer-story, top-tag

Looking at the [Developer Story](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/1243641) of [Scott Sauyet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1243641/scott-sauyet) - the [top user](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ramda.js/topusers) in [ramda.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ramda.js) - you don't see [ramda.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ramda.js). Why is this? Is this a bug? Do you need to have more questions or answers in [ramda.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ramda.js) to make it qualify for Developer Story? (I do not recall any such cap).

Comment: The user *chooses* which tags should be displayed there. Scott obviously does not want to brag about his knowledge of Ramda.JS. Perhaps too obscure?

Comment: Hmmm, just saw this, I don't recall even creating this page or adding anything.  But Ramda is there now.  And @CodyGray: *obscure*?  That's a way to hurt a guy!  :-)  Ramda has turned into a fairly big deal, with nearly a million daily NPM downloads, rather flabbergasting to me and to the friend who started it with me as a little educational project!